# neo4j plugin method signature mismatch

Tags: neo4j

In my Neo4j plugin I have a method:

```
@Procedure("myworld.implement")
public static Stream<MyItem> implement() {
    ...
```

When I invoke it in the browser:

```
call myworld.implement()
```

I get the response:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `myworld.implement`: Caused by: 
java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert 
MethodHandle()Stream to (Object)Object
```

How is there a mismatch between my method declaration and my method invocation?

(Neo4j 3.0.1 Community Edition)

Comment: when I call `call dbms.procedures()` I get:

`myworld.implement       myworld.implement() :: (name :: STRING?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should not have declared the method as *static*

correct:

```
@Procedure("myworld.implement")
public Stream<MyItem> implement() {
    ...
```